# How to keep primefaces dialog open with javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog

I have a problem with `primefaces` dialog. I have custom validation.
I created javascript method to keep the dialog opened when custom validation fails.
But although validation fails, it keeps closing.

Here is my code:

```
function alertMsg()
    {
        var str1 = document.getElementById("templateForm:resultMsg").textContent;
        var str2 = "Duplicate name.";
        if(str1.localeCompare(str2) == 0)
        {
            alert("inside same!")
            PF(dlg).show(); //Although i try to keep open, this dialog always close.
        }
    }

 .....some code
<p:dialog header="Add" widgetVar="dlg" id="add" resizable="false" modal="true" closable="false" width="600px" >
<h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5" > 
    <p:outputLabel value="Name" style="width:130px;"/>
    <p:outputLabel  value=":" style="width:15px;"/>
    <h:inputText id="Name" value="#{Bean.Name}" styleClass="form-control"  style="width:300px;" required="true" requiredMessage="!" >
    </h:inputText>
    <h:outputText id="resultMsg1" value="Duplicate name." style="color:red; width:30px;"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:commandButton process="@parent" ajax="true" value="Save" onstart="alertMsg()"
                                    update= templateForm:resultMsg" action="#{Bean.save()}" styleClass="btn btn-danger">
                                    </p:commandButton>

</p:dialog>
```

Comment: try using `return false;` at your js function.

Comment: still cannot work, keep closing.

Comment: i also think that you may want `actionListener` instead of `action` but im not 100% sure.

Comment: it works. :D Thanks alot @Apostolos. :)

Comment: Can you explain what is different between action and actionListener.

Comment: i'm just new for primefaces dialog

Comment: i posted also a link with another user's explanation for the diffs between them. hope it helps you!

Comment: ok, but i got some effect on save() when i use actionListener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118507/discussion-between-apostolos-and-alice).

Comment: Normally no one closes a dialog but you. I can't find a `PF(dlg).hide()` If the dialog will be closed without that, the page or a part of the page with your dialog was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use `actionLinstener` instead of `action`

you can find detailed explanation of both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)